# Write a function int caluculate_sum(int *a, int size) that calculates the sum of all the elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays

This is what I was given to start with.

```
     int main(){
      int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
      printf("Sum of elements of a: %d\n", calculate_sum(a,5));
      return 0;          
     }
```

Here's what I've got, I don't know why it doesn't work, please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
      int b;
      int calculate_sum(int, int);
      b = *a;

      printf("Sum of elements of a: %d\n", calculate_sum(b,5));
      return 0;          

}

int caluculate_sum(int *a, int size) 
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
        sum = sum + a[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `calculate_sum`, not `caluculate_sum`

Comment: thanks, the funtion prototype didnt match the cal, thNKS, I KNEW IT WAS SOMETHING MALL.

Answer (score 2):

Your function looks fine. Use the original main() that was given to you without any changes. Your function prototype

```
int calculate_sum(int*, int);
```

should be above your main and functions. If you're writing this all in one file, a good place for the prototypes is below your #include statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your function declaration,

```
int calculate_sum(int, int);
```

does not match your function definition,

```
int caluculate_sum(int *a, int size)
```

(note that the name is misspelled in the definition and type of the first parameter is different--it needs to be a pointer in the declaration).

Generally, [as MahlerFive points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838045/write-a-function-int-caluculatesumint-a-int-size-that-calculates-the-sum-of/1838080#1838080), it's good practice to declare all of your functions before you define them and not to place function declarations inside of other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Havent tested it.. but i guess this would work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate_sum(int, int);
int main(){ 
int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};      
//int b;         
//b = *a;      
//printf("Sum of elements of a: %d\n", calculate_sum(b,5));
printf("Sum of elements of a: %d\n", calculate_sum(a,5)); // you can directly pass an array     
return 0;          
}

//int caluculate_sum(int *a, int size) {
int caluculate_sum(int a, int size) {    
int i;    int sum = 0;    
for(i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)        
sum = sum + a[i];    
return sum;}
```

Comment: if you want to pass pointer to array in the function then you might want to change the function body.The function you have written is for taking array as such.